# Access 2013: Why am I getting this Syntax Error?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, ms-access-2013

Before I added the case statements, I was not receiving an error.  I needed to add the case statements to supply the home phone number as a backup if the H1 or H2 cell phone fields are blank or null (best way I know how to do it, as a novice).  For some reason I am getting a Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression.  It notes the error for both case statements.  As far as I can tell, they are written correctly... anyone know what's up?  Thanks.

```
SELECT [H1 Last Name] & ", " & [H1 First Name] as [Full Name],[H1 E-Mail]
CASE
     WHEN [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL
     THEN [Home Phone]
     ELSE [H1 Cell Phone] END as [Phone]

FROM NameLookup 
WHERE (((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) NOT LIKE '%SPEC%') OR ((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) NOT LIKE '%MODEL%')) AND ((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) IS NOT NULL)

UNION

SELECT [H2 Last Name] & ", " & [H2 First Name] as [Full Name],[H2 E-Mail]
CASE
     WHEN [H2 Cell Phone] IS NULL
     THEN [Home Phone]
     ELSE [H2 Cell Phone] END as [Phone]

FROM NameLookup 
WHERE (((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) NOT LIKE '%SPEC%') OR ((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) NOT LIKE '%MODEL%')) AND ((NameLookup.[H1 Last Name]) IS NOT NULL)


Order By 1;
```

Comment: You missed a comma after `[h1 email]`

Comment: I think a possible mistake is use of ORDER BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using that in MS Access ACE? Case is not available, use `IIF(argument, true value, false value)`

```
SELECT [H1 Last Name] & ", " & [H1 First Name] as [Full Name],[H1 E-Mail],
IIF ( [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL, [Home Phone], [H1 Cell Phone] ) AS Phone
FROM NameLookup
```

Access SQL Functions: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/

Comment: This is sort of working for me, and I believe you are right, CASE does not work for me here no matter what.  Yes, I am using this in Access (I am more familiar with SQL Server, although only enough to be dangerous).  Thank you.

The issue I still have is that when the union occurs, all of the Home Phone numbers which were not used, because the Cell Phone was not null, are displayed with blank Full Names ( just has a bunch of commas in the Full Name Column, no E-mail, and then all the Home Phone numbers which were not used).

Comment: I have no idea why you have a union, what is the difference between the two statements?

Comment: I am trying to combine basically information from four columns into one column for a query: H1 = HomeOwner 1 and H2 = Homeowner 2, they both live in the same home but I would like to gather all names and list in one column for a different purpose.  So I need to Combine "H1 Last, H1 First" and "H2 Last, H1 First" and also display their contact information (which H1 and H2 each have their own e-mail and cell phone).  If the cell phone is blank I would like it to default to the home phone number.  Does that makes sense?  Thank you..

Comment: Picture of the current [output:](http://picpaste.com/a0b0069a6fec64d1259d4da8694e5cc1.PNG).  I have circled in red where the list begins to correctly show names and numbers merged.

Comment: Do you have a Last Name and First Name for those rows? Because it looks like you do not.

Comment: In other words, the result is correct. Perhaps you would like to add a WHERE statement. WHERE [Last Name] Is Not Null, for example. The IIF statement will return Null if Home Phone is Null.

Comment: Yes, I noticed I had an error in the second select WHERE.  I was checking for Null in the wrong column. Thank you!!!  Getting much closer to what I need..  Now what I can't figure out is why my "IS NOT LIKE" statements still continue to pull in items where [H1 Last Name] contains "SPEC".  This is the only column that contains this information.. current code is [here](http://pastebin.com/WNDq9dn6)

Comment: I will add a new thread/question because I believe the original question has been answered, thank you. The new thread is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257034/access-2013-sql-is-not-like-issue).  Thanks everyone & @Remou for all your help getting me this far.