# Access 2013 SQL: "IS NOT LIKE" issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I cannot figure out why my WHERE clause seems to still return column values where the value is "SPEC"...  what am I doing wrong here?  [H1 Last Name] is the only column which contains this designation/value.

```
SELECT [H1 LAST Name] & ", " & [H1 FIRST Name] AS [FULL Name],
       [H1 E-Mail] AS [E-Mail],
       IIF([H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL, [Home Phone], [H1 Cell Phone]) AS Phone
FROM   NameLookup
WHERE  ((NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%SPEC%') OR (NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%MODEL%'))
  AND  (NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] IS NOT NULL)

UNION ALL

SELECT [H2 LAST Name] & ", " & [H2 FIRST Name] AS [FULL Name],
       [H2 E-Mail] AS [E-Mail],
       IIF([H2 Cell Phone] IS NULL, [Home Phone], [H2 Cell Phone]) AS Phone
FROM   NameLookup
WHERE  ((NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%SPEC%') OR (NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%MODEL%'))
  AND  (NameLookup.[H2 LAST Name] IS NOT NULL)

ORDER BY [FULL NAME]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wild card characters for `LIKE` are different depending on the context where the query runs.

From ADO, the wild cards are `%` and `_`:

```sql
NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%SPEC%'
```

From DAO, the wild cards are `*` and `?`:

```sql
NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '*SPEC*'
```

Or you could use `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE`, and then the db engine will always expect `%` and `_` wild cards regardless of the context where the query runs:

```sql
NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT ALIKE '%SPEC%'
```

Comment: This worked for me, I can't believe it was that simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your query accepts records where

```
(NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%SPEC%') OR (NameLookup.[H1 LAST Name] NOT LIKE '%MODEL%')
```

so if the last name does not contain 'MODEL' but does contain 'SPEC' it will make it into your results.

Comment: Yes, that is correct as well, I will need to change to AND I believe.  Thank you.